# How to navigate / process atom entry links in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, atom-feed

I need to parse an atom document, where entry links point to other related entries. For example, an entry contains information about an electric meter, and a link points to another entry which contains readings made by that meter. Exact structure is:

https://collaborate.nist.gov/twiki-sggrid/pub/SmartGrid/GreenButtonSDK/ESPISchemaOverview.png

Can anyone give me a tip/starting point? I know basics about XML parsing in Java but navigating between entries using links just boggles my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like [ROME](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home) to parse the feed would give you the feed as a collection of [`Entry`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/rome/rome/1.0.0/rome-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/com/sun/syndication/feed/atom/Entry.html) objects. Each `Entry` has a collection of [`Link`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/rome/rome/1.0.0/rome-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/com/sun/syndication/feed/atom/Link.html)s, including possible a link to itself (`rel='self'`) to assign a permalink.

Navigating between entries may well involve iterating over all the entries to find the target, or you could build your own `Map`. This doesn't take care of the logic of making the appropriate connections due to the links but it does get you the data in terms of identifiers and links.

Comment: So, I have to compare one entry's "self" link with other's "related" link to determine that entry is associated with that one, am I right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Without seeing a concrete example it's hard to see exactly how that schema would map to link relations.